# How many projects in a solution is too many?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

How many projects in a single solution is acceptable?  And for those apps that have large project numbers do you put the other compiled dlls in some common folder to be able to run the app?

Comment: Lots of "fuzzy" factors affect the scalability of projects in a solution. How powerful is your machine? How patient are you? How many solutions do you need to open concurrently? Do you like ice-cream? How long is a peice of string? . . .

Comment: If you keep asking yourself whether there are too many projects, there are probably too many projects!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since in Visual Studio a project compiles to an assembly, the question you should ask yourself is "how many assemblies should I have?"

If there's no reason for the assemblies to be used separately, there should be no reason to have them split in several projects. If you have several assemblies to enforce layering, that's what namespaces are for.

In an ideal setup, you should have one project (= one assembly) for each different host in your application, and one for your non-host specific logic.

YMMV though, you may want to split projects according to who is working on the different parts, but really, try to limit the number of projects in your solution (as I'm writing this, I'm struggling with a 70+ projects solution, so I'm talking from the abysses of my personal experience).

A interesting discussion on logical/physical layering of applications can be found on Patrick Smacchia's blog (for instance http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/10/layering-the-level-metric-and-the-discourse-of-method.aspx )

Comment: The problem a single project is that you will run into problems should you need to reuse your code from a new application. Do you really want to load all your business logic and other layers into an app that doesn't need it? The problem with breaking them apart is that once you break apart one of them you will be breaking apart many (ie. 42 example). I think more projects are then better if you plan to grow eventually or build a platform. If your application will never be reused, use a single project. Also, I think it is better to organize and have a new tool in your belt by splitting them up.

Comment: One other other thing, is that there is nothing stopping you from using multiple solutions(.sln files) for a sub groups of the same projects. Not only that but it is totally okay to overlap projects to those solutions since they are logical mappings to the same files. Then you can work on those logical groupings as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Well, 42, of course!

Answer (score 2):

There is no right or wrong answer to this.  Some developers like to create multiple projects within the main project.  Others like to compile to an assembly (the dll) and reference back.  It depends on your team and workplace.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answers so far. One additional criterion is the speed of rebuilding the solution...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something that depends on the size and type of your projects . but from my own experience when my number of projects is more than 5 the build process will take long .
so I try to keep projects that I do not need to change frequently in another solution in order  to make the build process faster .

Answer (score 0):

As long as each project is a valid, separate functionality, and all the projects are closely coupled (as far as purpose goes), then it isn't a problem.

What I do, is I have a "Libraries" project where I put all my external DLLs, then reference them directly there.